# UIWebview is content editable and I am able to enter text but after two line I am able to enter text but text are not visible in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

[image]

I creating my own Rich Text Editor & using webview

```
    NSString *htmlStrToShow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body  bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\" contenteditable =\"true\">%@</body>",htmlStrToShow];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStrToShow baseURL:nil];
```

and also used

```
[_self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@" document.body.contentEditable =\"true\"; document.designMode=\"on\";"];
```

but we can see in image after two lines content size of editable area in not increasing.
It happens only in `iOS7` Device

Comment: I have solved this problem, it seems problem occurs because of [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStrToShow baseURL:nil]. when i call [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStrToShow baseURL:nil] more than one time this problem occur. To solve this I allocated new webview and issue fixed but this is not a right solution. If you have any other solution please suggest.